# VirtualBox 7.0.12 - Upgrade Raspberry pi os desktop 32 to 64 bit

Tags: virtualization

I apologize in advance for any errors or mistakes in Debian (or Linux in general) but I have never used it before and I am just starting to approach it.

Basically, my goal is to run Raspberry Pi OS on VirtualBox. Currently on the VM (created with Debian 12 OS - 64 bit - 8 GB of RAM - 4 cores - 30 GB HDD) it was created with the ISO of the 32-bit desktop version (as the various 64-bit versions were all in .img format).

I was wondering if there is a way to upgrade the OS to 64-bit directly from the VirtualBox VM.

To date, I have tried several ways directly from my PC (not on the VirtualBox VM with Raspberry OS at 32 bit):

Tried to convert .img file to ISO (with imgburn) and to vdi (with the VirtualBox tool) and try to recreate a new VM on VirtualBox but without success
Tried essentially the same steps with qemu
Thank you in advance to everyone for any suggestions or help.

Comment: `the various 64-bit versions were all in .img format` where do you see any 64 bit images for "raspberry pi desktop"?

Comment: I meant os like Raspberry Pi OS with desktop (https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/operating-systems/#raspberry-pi-os-64-bit). Excuse me for the imprecision, as I said I am only now approaching the world of virtualization and Linux in general.

Comment: Oh, you mean the arm64 not amd64? Is what you want the one that is `"Compatible with: PC and Mac"`

Comment: Yes, i would set up mu virtualbox with raspberry pi os 64-bit

Comment: for intel/amd processors? Raspberry pi foundation only release 32bit (i386) not 64bit (amd64) images - because ... the 64 bit version would be indistinguishable from plain ol Debian